# Print second column values in a nested loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have following variable file

```
cluster1:
  projects:
    - project_name: project1
      groups:
        admin: foo1
        edit: bar1
        view: bar2
      id: ramdom
```

I am trying to print the values in the second column under groups.
e.g.

```
foo1
bar1
bar2
```

I have tried with the following playbook, but it didn't work as I expected and also I stuck at finding a logic to print only the second column..

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ cluster1.projects.groups }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.groups.values()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ cluster1.projects }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - foo1
  - bar1
  - bar2
```

---

Fit the output to your needs, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for value in _values %}
          {{ value }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ cluster1.projects }}"
      vars:
        _values: "{{ item.groups.values()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    foo1
    bar1
    bar2
```